# M$ Ergonomic keyboard on 16.04

Tags: keyboard, wireless-keyboards

The time is fast approaching for me to replace my original M$ Natural keyboard (which I've been using on all of my main PCs since 1996!  Pretty good value for money, methinks).

I have my eye on the newer versions, the Ergonomic 4000 and the Sculpt Ergonomic wireless offering.

Does anybody have any experience of either of these, are there any known issues that I haven't found in my searches?

Bog standard connection to a PC base unit, nothing fancy involved :)

Comment: Wildly OT, but you can read the comments here: http://theonlinephotographer.typepad.com/the_online_photographer/2016/12/ergonomic-keyboards-ot.html --- I do not think that the keyboard will behave differently in Linux, really.

Comment: Hello,

Maybe your question is a bit off-topic here. but I had a Sculpt Comfort and it worked fine.